# How to position text after icon in CSS?

Tags: css, icons

I'm trying to position a text after an icon, but for some reason the text is glued to the icon, instead of going under it.

I have the following code:

```css
.appbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  /* align-items:center; */
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.6);
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #555555;
  !important
}

.appbox_image {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 72px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: left!important;
  float: none!important;
  clear: both!important;
}

.appbox_text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: left!important;
  float: none!important;
  clear: both!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="appbox">
  <div class="appbox_image">
    <img src='../images/app-newtext.png'></div>
  <div class="appbox_text">Create a new context and visualise the text inside.</div>
</div>
```

However, as a result I get this:

[image]

What to change so that the text appears under the image and is not the same width as the image but a bit wider, fitting into the space of the `appbox` (but with the padding still applied).

Thank you!

Comment: can you try to remove .appbox diplay flex

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!
I changed your css so that the image and text display `inline-block` instead of `block`. The HTML is altered only slightly. I applied the image css to the img tag and to the text via a paragraph tag, and I put both `img` and `p` into one div and  I tidied up your css a bit (put the `padding` into shorthand, and grouped the css that was common to both text and image together).

An alternative to having an inner div would be to set the `flex-direction` in the outer div css, and remove the inline-block from the app_image/text css. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/dzmuwvea/)). This will center the image - was unclear if you wanted the image left or center. If you want it to the left you can always adjust the css to display the image to the left.

Hope this helps

```css
.appbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction:column;*/
  float: left;
  /* align-items:center; */
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.6);
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  /* top, right, bottom, left*/
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #555555!important;
}

.appbox_image {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 72px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.appbox_image,
.appbox_text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  float: none!important;
  clear: both!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="appbox">
  <div>
    <img class="appbox_image" src='../images/app-newtext.png'>
    <p class="appbox_text">Create a new context and visualise the text inside. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```